# Flexpaper Flash version - Disable/Hide Print

Tags: flash, pdf, flexpaper

I am using the Flexpaper version where you convert PDF files to flash. In the flash based viewer i need to either disable or hide the print option. Checked for such Parameters in the Flexpaper site, (http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs_parameters.jsp) but couldn't find an option. IS there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is by using the read only viewer. The drawback is that you lose the other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Found a blog post where its done in a different version of Flexpaper but this requires flex a project. I'm a .Net person with a very limited idea about flex at the moment. Anyway thought it would be helpful

http://sevpuri.blogspot.com/2013/04/disable-print-option-in-flexpaper-41.html

Comment: If there's anyother way please let me know